# This site results in less Q & A and more discussion

Tags: discussion

This site is turning into a xda clone. Most of the questions I have observed result in a discussion. I rarely see any definite answers.

This is my experience. Is that yours as well?

Edited: These are a few examples, I could fetch.
Examples:

> [How to get Waze alerts in Google Navigation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53405/how-to-get-waze-alerts-in-google-navigation)
>
> [Why does my Nexus 5 keep forgetting all wifi passwords after a reboot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62025/why-does-my-nexus-5-keeps-on-forgetting-all-wifi-passwords-after-a-reboot)
>
> https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60742/is-there-an-app-to-take-pictures-from-the-lock-screen-before-unlocking-shooti?rq=1

Comment: Could you share some links to example Qs you are talking about?

Comment: If you go round asking, "Is that yours as well?" no wonder everything turns into a discussion.

Answer (score 7):

Comments are the second class citizens of Stack Exchange - discussion in comments to help clarify the meaning and intentions of a question are absolutely acceptable with the intention that once the question has been clarified, the comments get cleaned up.

The "questions" in each instance you've linked ask for a focussed answer relating to a specific problem. Most of the answers are a bit low quality and could probably be converted into comments in the instances that you've linked, but you must keep in mind that there is no guarantee when dealing with a third party platform (like this site is - Android) that there is actually an answer to every question.

Since the Stack Exchange platform is a community driven engine, if *you* feel that some of the answers are not really answers, there are tools at your disposal to rectify this:

- You can flag answers that are not an answer but should probably be kept (since they give good, workable advice) with a "flag for moderator attention" so that they can be converted into comments

  - This doesn't apply to answers that attempt to answer the question, even if they're wrong
  - It also doesn't apply to answers that attempt to provide a workaround
- If the answer doesn't answer the question, you can flag it as "not an answer" which will place it in a queue to be reviewed and acted on

  - This is the correct flag to use if you feel the answer is actually a discussion
  - Don't use these flags if the answer is an attempt to answer the question but is ultimately wrong (that's what downvotes are for)

Comment: I agree about not having an answer to every question. that's the reason I mention that this site is turning into a discussion forum rather than Q & A.

Comment: So what would you propose, making questions that don't have a answer off topic? That's certainly not the right way to approach this kind of problem. If a question doesn't have an answer - that's pretty much how it should be presented within the Stack Exchange engine - a question that doesn't have an answer.

Comment: And just because a question doesn't have an answer at the moment doesn't mean it will never have an answer. The Waze question you linked to is a good example of this.